# External annotation processor not working

Tags: java, maven, gradle, annotations, meta-annotation

I'm trying to use [Jilt](https://github.com/skinny85/jilt) in several projects. Since I'm using the same builder annotation in all of them, I thought it would be a good idea to do a custom annotation in a common library which could be used then wherever necessary. The common library is [jilt-common](https://github.com/thmasker/jilt-common). For testing purposes, I've created also a project which imports this library: [jilt-test](https://github.com/thmasker/jilt-test).

Well, Jilt does not seem to work this way. First thing I saw is `@Builder` and `@BuilderInterfaces` retention policies (`SOURCE`) prevent those annotations to remain in the compiled source, so when jilt-test uses jilt-common builder annotation, it is not a jilt builder anymore. So I forked the repository and added `CLASS` retention policy for both annotations. You can check it here: [common-test](https://github.com/thmasker/jilt/tree/common-test). With this change, annotations are preserved, but processor is still ignoring them.

I don't really know what else to do. It somehow makes sense for me that this does not work, since jilt-test only uses already compiled classes of jilt-common, so I guess the processors are obviously ignoring that. But I also guess there must be some way to make this work.